Bluetooth audio crackling sound
I'm using a Thinkpad E14 under Debian 12 with KDE Plasma, and listening to music through bluetooth in A2DP.
When I use a large bandwidth of Wifi (streaming video, or uploading/downloading files) the audio looses a lot in quality, and generates crackling sounds, as long as the bandwidth is high.
I've seen information that suggests this might be coming from the bluetooth/wifi chip. But it all works perfectly well on Windows. This is my second Debian 12 installation on this exact computer, and it did work well previously.
Does anyone know what settings, what software, driver etc. I should be installing or configuring in order to resolve this issue ?
Thanks
